# Custom Response to display the data in list of JSON using django

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='org_project',null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='product_project')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_project')
    project_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    project_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    project_cost = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    currency_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES, default='Indian Rupee')
    project_head = models.ForeignKey(User_Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_head',null=True)
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(User_Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_manager',null=True)
    project_user = models.ManyToManyField(User_Master,related_name='project_user')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    techstack = models.ManyToManyField(Techstack,related_name='techstack_project')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

**views.py**

```
from djmoney.settings import CURRENCY_CHOICES

class CurrencyList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(CURRENCY_CHOICES, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I was Trying to get the Currency code list in a response so that the data can be sent to the frontend as a dropdown list.

When I Used the above django money package I am getting an response as

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        [
            "XUA",
            "ADB Unit of Account"
        ],
        [
            "AFN",
            "Afghan Afghani"
        ],
        [
            "AFA",
            "Afghan Afghani (1927–2002)"
        ],
        ....
],
    "message": null
}
```

But I need to Get the response as list of json inside the data not as the list of arrays,

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "shortname": "XUA",
            "fullname": "ADB Unit of Account"
        },
        {
            "shortname":"AFN",
            "fullname":"Afghan Afghani"
        },
        {
            "shortname":"AFA",
            "fullname":"Afghan Afghani (1927–2002)"
        },
        ....
],
    "message": null
}
```

Is it possible to modify the response for this package? or is there any other way to achieve the end goal response by any other method?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adjust your response in the following way:

```
from djmoney.settings import CURRENCY_CHOICES

class CurrencyList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(
            [{'shortname': short, 'fullname': full} for short, full in CURRENCY_CHOICES],
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from djmoney.settings import CURRENCY_CHOICES

class CurrencyList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response([dict(zip(['shortname', 'fullname'], c)) for c in CURRENCY_CHOICES], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

python console

```
>>> data = [
...         [
...             "XUA",
...             "ADB Unit of Account"
...         ],
...         [
...             "AFN",
...             "Afghan Afghani"
...         ],
...         [
...             "AFA",
...             "Afghan Afghani (1927–2002)"
...         ]
         ]
>>> 
>>> [dict(zip(['shortname', 'fullname'], c)) for c in data ]
[{'shortname': 'XUA', 'fullname': 'ADB Unit of Account'}, {'shortname': 'AFN', 'fullname': 'Afghan Afghani'}, {'shortname': 'AFA', 'fullname': 'Afghan Afghani (1927–2002)'}]
```